# restsharp with portable project

Tags: portable-class-library, restsharp

I try to install the package in a portable project but get the error :
Impossible to install the package « RestSharp 105.2.3 ». 
You try to install the package in a project « .NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111 »

Comment: Please add more information to your problem. What exactly is your question?

Comment: What version is compatible with this target type :